# Monge and Kantorovich problem in optimal transport

Tags: optimization, optimal-transport

It is well-known that in optimal transport, Kantorovich problem is a relaxation of the Monge problem, which always admits a solution. Let's write
$$ M(\mu,\nu)=\inf_{T: T_\#\mu=\nu} \int c(x,T(x))d\mu $$
$$K(\mu,\nu)=\inf_{\pi: \pi \; \text{has marginals}\;\mu\;\text{and}\;\nu} \int c(x,y)d\pi $$

I am interested in understanding what happens when the optimal value functions of these two problem are the same: $M(\mu,\nu)=K(\mu,\nu)<\infty$. In this case, does the Monge problem admit a solution? If not, what would be a counterexample? In addition, when the Monge problem has a solution, is it necessarily true that $M(\mu,\nu)=K(\mu,\nu)<\infty$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a paper with the example I am looking for:
On the equality between Monge’s infimum
and Kantorovich’s minimum in optimal mass transportation
by Aldo Pratelli

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your question. About that, as far as I know the Monge formulation, unlike Kantorovich’s, does not permit mass splitting, is that correct?